# Resize an image in HTML/CSS for mobile devices

Tags: html, image

I have a background image and I really can't figure out how to resize it for mobile devices... I've tried everything! Width: 100%, max-width: 100%; etc.
Is it the height/cover thats affecting it?

```
.jumbotron {
  background-image:url('http://www.part-box.com/images/yellow-frog.png');
  height: 500px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: what exactly do you want to get? stretch over the whole page? specific size? relative size to original? relative size to page?

Comment: I want the image to cover the full width of the page, but resize responsively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Media queries can solve this. calculate the width for the mobile and the other device.

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
        .jumbotron {
           background-image:url('http://www.part-box.com/images/yellow-frog.png');
            height: 200px; // customize it
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
              }
    }

 @media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
        .jumbotron {
           background-image:url('http://www.part-box.com/images/yellow-frog.png');
            height: 500px; //customize it
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
              }
    }
```

OR you can integrate the html with bootstrap that makes the code responsive across all platforms.

Comment: hmm yeah i suppose the @media will work - maybe just not as smooth.

Comment: How do you integrate bootstrap into this?

Comment: not in the css, but the html needs to be added with bootstrap 3.0 scripts and css, Read more about it on http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

CSS:

```
width: 100vw;
```

Adding a viewport and using vw allows
you to size elements relative to the total
width of the screen. Eg. 100vw takes up the full
width of the screen, regardless of it's size.

If the screen is 430px wide, it'll be 430 pixels wide.
Screen is 1200px wide, so will the element be.

1vw is 1% of the total screen width.